# How to make id field reset every day

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to create an column id that looks like this ID220321001 where 220321 is the date when the data is inserted and 001 is the auto incremented value.

But I need to reset the auto increment value to 1 whenever the date changed. How can I achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: So much of the world manages to work with `identity` ids that simply increment.  If you really want such a specialized id, you'll need to use a trigger -- or calculate it using a query.

Comment: Alternatively, use a `VIEW` and `ROW_NUMBER` to generate the value; just ensure you don't `DELETE` rows and instead mark them as "inactive" (or some similar terminology).

Comment: You would be far better off just storing the date and calculating your bespoke ID using a query or possibly a `view` would for you.

Comment: i see so using identity is not good for this, thanks for comment. But i am really new at sql can someone give me an practical example to do this? i would make it accepted. thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is some example data and a view that creates a custom ID value in the format you cite. This won't be exactly how you need to use it but should get you on your way.

```
create table Example (Id int, [Date] date)
insert into Example
select 1,'20210319' union all
select 1,'20210320' union all
select 2,'20210319' union all
select 2,'20210320' union all
select 3,'20210319' union all
select 3,'20210319' union all
select 3,'20210320' union all 
select 4,'20210318' union all 
select 4,'20210318' union all 
select 4,'20210319' union all 
select 4,'20210319' union all 
select 4,'20210319' union all 
select 4,'20210320' 

create view ExampleID as
select Id, [Date], 
    'ID' +
    Right('0' + RTrim(Day(Date)), 2) +
    Right('0' + RTrim(Month(Date)), 2) +
    Right(Cast(Year(Date) as varchar(4)), 2) + 
    Right('000' + Cast(Row_Number() over (partition by Id, Date order by Date) as varchar(3)),3) 
    as IdColumn
from Example

go

select *
from ExampleID
order by Id
```